# better structure of a software project to prevent circular dependencies

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented-design, dependency-injection, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am contacting you today regarding a recent problem with circular dependencies. It's about a Spring boot application that accepts data via a Rest API and then forwards it to an internal Spring service. When a new vehicle is to be created, then first a CarDto is submitted via Rest. The controller uses a car mapper (Mapstruct) to create a car object from it and passes it to the CarService. However, the CarService cannot save the object immediately. First, the object is enriched with further information. This information comes from a web service. If an error occurs during the retrieval (e.g. because the manufacturer is not known to the web service), an exception is thrown and the CarService does not perform persistence. However, if the web service receives a result, it expands the object using the vehicle mapper (also a map construct) and returns the object to the service. The service can now save the object. For its functionality, however, the mapper absolutely needs access to the CarService to retrieve further information from the database in order to extend the Car object.

Now comes the difficult point: the information from the web service can change in principle. This means that the information in the database must be regularly compared with the web service. For this purpose, the following steps must be taken:

- Pull all car objects from the database (due to the quantity with paging).
- Synchronize objects with web service
- Update objects in case of changes
- then persist them again

Currently I have this functionality stuck in the VehicleService. To fetch the elements and save them, however, it needs the CarService (circular dependency). I could now put the sync function in the CarService, but then the question is when the translation from the Vehicle to the Car object should take place. If the translation should take place within the VehicleService, then I need the VehicleMapper in the VehicleServices. However, the VehicleMapper needs the CarService again. If I want to map the returns of the web service to a Car object in the VehicleService, I only need a DTO for the transfer of the information from the Car to the VehicleService. I don't really like that either.

I have hope that you guys have tips. Gladly also with the consequence eiens Refactorings.

For better illustration I have created a small class diagram. Please forgive me if not all characters fit perfectly - unfortunately I am not an uml expert.

[image: UML]

Comment: *Stable dependency principle* - Clean Architecture by R.C.Martin.

Comment: Why can't VehicleService use the CarRepository for data access needs? Then you don't need the CarService in VehicleService, unless I'm misunderstanding the problem.

Comment: These arrows do not seem to be dependency arrows. If they are they point in the wrong direction.

Comment: I don't understand why you need a CarService and a VehicleService.  A car *is a* vehicle.  What does the CarService do that VehicleService doesn't?  Or rather, what prevents you from collapsing these into a single service?

Comment: Also, your sync process, if I understand it correctly, is very inefficient.  It's not the question you are asking but if you add data to your DB about when things last changed, you can avoid retrieving everything every time.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your answers.@JimmyJames:

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your answers.@JimmyJames: Actually I wanted to separate the communication with the webservice. The webservice is called VehicleWebservice, so the service is called VehicleService. I don't understand your sync hint yet. The data changes in the webservice. But I can't tell the webservice, Show me changes since date x. That means I have to compare my data set from the database with the data of the webservice. What is the use of a last changed property on my DB?

Comment: Until now, I have always assumed that it is a good practice to protect the repository from access from other packages and to handle access via a service. I use packages-by-feature. The webservice matching is actually in com.company.vehiclewebservice and the car elements (entity, repository, service, dto, mapper) in com.company.car.